# Excel HYPERLINK with INDEX MATCH reference isn’t valid

Tags: excel, indexing, hyperlink, match

I have set up a set of forms on excel that can append or update information to an access database.

Due to their being multiple forms, I want to create a spreadsheet, which acts as a hyperlink centre to the form the user needs.

Their are only to ‘branches’ of forms the users can use:

Add new data forms
And
Update Existing data forms

Each of these branches has say, 5 forms (so 10 in total)

The spreadsheet I’ve set up has two tabs

Tab 1 - user end sheet (‘user’)
Tab 2 - list and hyperlinks (‘info’)

On the user end sheet there is a list to select which branch of forms the user wants the link to (Cell D11)

Add
Or
Update

From there a secondary dependant drop down list shows the forms available from that branch (Cell D16)

Finally, there is a cell which I’d like to display the hyperlink to the form they have selected.

I’ve searched around a lot, however I can’t find the fix.

The formula in full is:

=IF(user!D16=“”,””,IF(user!D11=“Add”,HYPERLINK(“#”&INDEX(info!$D$9:$E$13,MATCH(user!D16,info!$D$9:$E$13,0)),(VLOOKUP(D16,info!$D$9:$E$13,2,0))),HYPERLINK(“#”&INDEX(info!$G$9:$H$13,MATCH(user!D16,info!$G$9:$H$13,0)),(VLOOKUP(user!D16,info!$G$9:$H$13,2,0)))))

The hyperlink formulas:

HYPERLINK(“#”&INDEX(info!$D$9:$E$13,MATCH(user!$D$16,info!$D$9:$E$13,0))

And

HYPERLINK(“#”&INDEX(info!$G$9:$H$13,MATCH(user!$D$16,info!$G$9:$H$13,0))

The result simply returns #N/A

I’ve tried:

INDEX

“#&INDEX(…)”

“#”&”INDEX(…)”

And knocking all of the if statements out, leaving only the hyperlink function there.

The hyperlinks work fine in the info tab.

Any help would be massively appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Issue was that the hyperlinks id set up already had a ‘friendly name’, changed to raw link and then was able to replace index match simply with Vlookups.